# Showing if that powers of matrices are similar, then so are the matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix and that $A^n$ and $B^n$ are similar for all sufficiently large $n$. I need to show that this implies that $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Since  $A^n$ and $B^n$ are similar, we have
$$B^n=XA^nX^{-1}$$
for some invertible $n \times n$ matrix $X$. How does the fact that this holds for all large $n$ imply that $A$ and $B$ are similar. Can I use diagonalization?

 Also, it's probably not true if $A$ is not invertible. What would an example of that be?

Comment: Would you want the same $X$ to be used for all $n$? :)

Comment: No, it cannot be the same $X$.

Comment: I am still not sure how to prove it though.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For the noninvertible case let $A$ a be a nonzero nilpotent matrix and let $B$ be the zero matrix.